# pandas InvalidIndexError when using aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I get an error (InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects) when trying to run this code, that creates a pivot_table out of a dataFrame:

```
pivData = dfData.pivot_table(values=["ppp", "vvv"],
                             index=["ccc", "iii", "ttt", "www"],
                             aggfunc=[np.sum, np.sum])
```

I don't get what is wrong. And when I remove the last argument, it works fine (just not doing a sum, but an average)

```
pivData = dfData.pivot_table(values=["ppp", "vvv"],
                             index=["ccc", "iii", "ttt", "www"])
```

If anyone has a solution or a workaround... Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small, self-contained example with sample data demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
pivData = dfData.pivot_table(values=["ppp", "vvv"],
                             index=["ccc", "iii", "ttt", "www"],
                             aggfunc=np.sum)
```